# Is it posible to redirect the user to the Android Accessibility Volume key shortcut?

Tags: android, android-intent, accessibility, settings

I'm trying to redirect the user to the "Volume key shortcut" screen (available from android 8.0) but I can't do it.

I'm know how to arrive to the previous screen using an intent with the action "Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS" but that's all.

Thanks in advance!